# IOS Shinobicharts memory leak

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi I created a view controller with multiple views in which each subview contains a shinobichart.  This view controller is push to a navigation controller.  Everything appears fine but when the view controller is popped from the navigation controller all of the memory used to render the charts does not get freed according to the xcode profiler.  Is there something I'm missing or is this a bug with shinobicharts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a leak. First, you'll want to check your code to see if you're somehow causing the problem. Is the view controller being deallocated? Are the charts being deallocated? In short, what objects are *not* being deallocated? Do you have strong references to any of those objects in your own code?

If you're pretty certain that your code isn't causing the leak you can start to suspect the ShinobiControls library. Create a new project that illustrates the problem as simply as possible. This will provide a simple, reproducible example that you can send to the ShinobiControls support staff along with your bug report.